# LoRa Server rf95.available() method returns false

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, lora

I'm trying to send basic information with LoRa(rf95) one Arduino to another. I have followed 
https://www.smart-prototyping.com/blog/Sending-and-Receiving-Weather-Data-with-a-LoRa-Module
[enter link description here](https://www.smart-prototyping.com/blog/Sending-and-Receiving-Weather-Data-with-a-LoRa-Module)
I am sure about pin connections. Then I used example rf95 server code in radiohead library. The problem is rf95.available() method returns false every time. I have no idea what is wrong with connection.

Code :

```
// rf95_server.pde
// -*- mode: C++ -*-
// Example sketch showing how to create a simple messageing server
// with the RH_RF95 class. RH_RF95 class does not provide for addressing or
// reliability, so you should only use RH_RF95  if you do not need the higher
// level messaging abilities.
// It is designed to work with the other example rf95_client
// Tested with Anarduino MiniWirelessLoRa, Rocket Scream Mini Ultra Pro with
// the RFM95W, Adafruit Feather M0 with RFM95

#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF95 rf95;
//RH_RF95 rf95(5, 2); // Rocket Scream Mini Ultra Pro with the RFM95W
//RH_RF95 rf95(8, 3); // Adafruit Feather M0 with RFM95 

// Need this on Arduino Zero with SerialUSB port (eg RocketScream Mini Ultra Pro)
//#define Serial SerialUSB

int led = 9;

void setup() 
{
  // Rocket Scream Mini Ultra Pro with the RFM95W only:
  // Ensure serial flash is not interfering with radio communication on SPI bus
//  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
//  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
  Serial.begin(38400);
  while (!Serial) ; // Wait for serial port to be available
  if (!rf95.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");  
  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, 13dBm, Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on

  // The default transmitter power is 13dBm, using PA_BOOST.
  // If you are using RFM95/96/97/98 modules which uses the PA_BOOST transmitter pin, then 
  // you can set transmitter powers from 5 to 23 dBm:
//  driver.setTxPower(23, false);
  // If you are using Modtronix inAir4 or inAir9,or any other module which uses the
  // transmitter RFO pins and not the PA_BOOST pins
  // then you can configure the power transmitter power for -1 to 14 dBm and with useRFO true. 
  // Failure to do that will result in extremely low transmit powers.
//  driver.setTxPower(14, true);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("init ");  
  if (rf95.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Available");  
    // Should be a message for us now   
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len))
    {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
//      RH_RF95::printBuffer("request: ", buf, len);
      Serial.print("got request: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
//      Serial.print("RSSI: ");
//      Serial.println(rf95.lastRssi(), DEC);

      // Send a reply
      uint8_t data[] = "And hello back to you";
      rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
      rf95.waitPacketSent();
      Serial.println("Sent a reply");
       digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("recv failed");
    }
  }else
    Serial.println("fail");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is one of the arduinos not plugged into a USB with a serial connection. If so then the code may be hanging at the line below.
while (!Serial) ; // Wait for serial port to be available

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the `int led = 9;` to `int led = 8;`

`9` is reserved for the `LoRa` module's RESET pin according to their own wiki:

The `RF95-server` sketch uses the `led=9` to show the status. Please change it to other LEDs, such as `8` because `9` is connected to the LoRa module's RESET pin.